# Change an array to a string without creating a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I wish to accomplish:

```
    String []beef = new String[3];
    beef[0] = "Water";
    beef[1] = "Chicken";
    beef[2] = "Paper";

    String empo = Arrays.toString(beef);

    if (empo.isEmpty()){
        empo = "Nothing";
        System.out.println(empo);
    }else{
        System.out.println(empo);
    }
```

without having to create the string.

Something like:

```
    String []beef = new String[3];
    beef[0] = "Water";
    beef[1] = "Chicken";
    beef[2] = "Paper";

    Arrays.toString(beef);  //change beef to just a plain string

    if(beef.isEmpty()||beef==""){
    no = "Nothing";

    System.out.println(beef);
```

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: You could use a for loop to print each letter in the array in the order it needs to be in.

Comment: Yea? However, what does that have to do with changing the array type, as per the main intent of my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You can't.

Java is a [strongly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) and [statically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) typed language. That means you have to tell it what type a thing will be when you declare it (strong typing), and you can't ever change it's type after that (static typing).

You will just have to create a new `String`.

Comment: So, more broadly, can you convert any data type to another without declaring a new variable?

Comment: @House no. Java is statically typed.

Comment: Is there an example of an un-statically typed programming language or something?

Comment: @House Javascript (and it's called "dynamically-typed")

Answer (score 1):

You can create substrings with the same backing memory as the original string, but you can't create a string with the same backing memory as an array of strings.  They're not stored in the same order so it's impossible to view the same memory both ways.

Comment: No you can't. Strings are immutable.

Comment: Strings being immutable has nothing to do with it.  The documentation for String.substring clearly states "The returned string shares this string's backing array."

Comment: But it creates a new `String`. You can't manipulate a `String` without making a new one.

Comment: It's a "new string", but it's backed by the same memory, which if you read my answer is what i said.  You "_create_ substrings" that have the "same backing memory".  I love being downvoted by people who either can't read or don't understand my undeniably accurate information.

Comment: okay, that technically doesn't *really* answer the question but -1 removed

Comment: The array doesn't go away until it's garbage-collected, and an array of strings and a string aren't stored in the same order in memory, so there's no way to reuse that memory.

Comment: Where can I read more about memory usage?
I don't know the right vocab to Google it.

Comment: "Optimization" is what you would google for info about either running faster or using less memory, though honestly they usually assume you know much of the vocab already. ...Anyway the key thing to understand is that variables are usually cheap, and there's good reason to create lots of them. More important than how many variables you have is how much memory they're using. If you have a lot of text, you can use less memory by creating the big combined string first, and then using substring to put pieces of it into an array. If you already have the array, you can't reuse it for the big string.

Comment: This stuff gets a lot more important once your programs get a lot bigger so don't worry about it so much for now.

Comment: Yea...way over my head. I'm just a bit ocd when it comes to java and thus I really like to keep things clean and efficient.
By using the least amount of "typage" to do the job, without compromising anything of course.

Guess in this case, it was over-optimization haha.